# Modify any Application Startup Android

Tags: android, android-intent

This is the first time I've delved into how applications are managed by default by the Android system and I have a few questions. Perhaps my thoughts are not even possible to do, so that's why I've come here to ask them.

This is just a hypothetical concept, but let's say I want to add a little extra something (say an image) before a particular application starts up. Could this be done? I give the user the opportunity to choose which applications he\she wants this image to appear on start up.

Could this be done by my application being the "default" configuration for these applications in the settings menu and then launching intents for the "real" applications after the image appears? Is there a best way to proceed with what I'm trying to do? I just wanted ask the question here because I figured many would have experience with this type of thing and know how to do it best.

Much appreciated for any insight on this type of activity!

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I can make a launcher type app with image code in it, assign particular applications to use my app for the default, then launch an "intent" in my app after the image has been shown. I'd have to capture the name of the application being launched somehow though.

Comment: No, this is not possible on a stock Android device.

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to implement a home screen. That home screen can, as do most home screens, offer the ability to launch "apps" (actually starting `LAUNCHER` activities). You are welcome to allow the user to configure additional stuff that you would do as part of starting that `LAUNCHER` activity, such as showing this "image".

> Could this be done by my application being the "default" configuration for these applications in the settings menu and then launching intents for the "real" applications after the image appears?

No.

> Perhaps I can make a launcher type app with image code in it, assign particular applications to use my app for the default, then launch an "intent" in my app after the image has been shown.

No.

Comment: I just downloaded the application called "Message Lock" that has a user pick a pattern and particular text applications are configured to work with the app. Their lock screen pattern prompt comes up before the texting application goes any further. I'm trying to figure out how this would be done.